# CodeIgniter URL suffix .html automatically for all URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am new in CodeIgniter.
I setup CI in my localhost Eg. localhost/MyProjects/CodeIgniter/welcome/index

I can able to remove the index.php from the url & I also completed the .html suffix 
So, I can able to visit localhost/MyProjects/CodeIgniter/welcome/index.html & Its working properly.

So I am using my a tag like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/register.html">Register</a>
```

But, I dont want to use the .html in my link manually.

have any solution to show my visitor .html suffix automatically Eg. localhost/MyProjects/CodeIgniter/welcome/index.html Or localhost/MyProjects/CodeIgniter/welcome/about.html Etc

Here is my htaccess http://pastebin.com/cXUFjvbp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just edit `url_suffix` in **config.php** .....

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
```

Use [**`site_url()`**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

```
<!-- No need .html -->
<a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/register'); ?>">Register</a>
<!-- <a href="http://domain/welcome/register.html">Register</a> -->
```

Or [**`anchor()`**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

```
// No need .html
echo anchor('welcome/register', 'Register');
// <a href="http://domain/welcome/register.html">Register</a>
```

***Note*** : Dont forget to load **URL helper** with `$this->load->helper('url');`.

Comment: Hello Friend, I used your method & now It's working fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: CI 3 Release Date: March 30, 2015. Answered May 19, 2014 :)

Answer (score 5):

Change your config.php file

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just redefine the base_url function or make a new one. Look at the [source](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Config.php#L278) of `base_url` method

```
function _base_url($path = NULL) {
  return base_url() . $path . '.html';
}
```

Comment: Make a new one is better solution. Or function _base_url($path = NULL, $suffix = "") {return base_url($path).$suffix}

Comment: Why need new function?

Comment: Thank you for your solution. :) But, I used @WahyuKristianto method.