# Codeigniter URL suffix not working

Tags: codeigniter, web-config

I tried a lot to get the result i.e. `.html` or `/` as URL suffix, but failed.

My `config.php` is like...

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/domain/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
```

My `web.config` is like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
         <rule name="Clean URL" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

My `autoload.php` is like...

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
```

My URL is showing like...

```
http://localhost/domain/view_details/get/some_details
```

where I want the URL like...

```
http://localhost/domain/view_details/get/some_details.html
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726776/codeigniter-url-suffix-html-automatically-for-all-url) and [this](http://www.vishwashgaur.com/open-source/url-rewriting-codeigniter/) also, but failed.

**What should I do ?**

Comment: What do you mean by showing. What happen when you hit .html link.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam First of all thanks for your answer. If I write `.html` after the link and hit, no problem happens, it shows/display the page properly. But `.html` is not append automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any code where you producing links. To produce a link you should use [site_url](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#site_url)

From your config.php

```
echo site_url('test');
//will produce 
//http://localhost/domain/test.html

echo site_url('view_details/get/some_details');
//will produce 
//http://localhost/domain/view_details/get/some_details.html
```

Comment: Thank you Shaiful Islam for the answer. It works. Thanks again.