# CodeignIter with HTTPS page not rendering domain/H.html not working(404 Error)

Tags: codeigniter, https

Website is normally working without HTTPS.

with HTTPS only homepage is working but other pages like (https://domain.in/contact.html) not working(**404 Error Page**)

My Files.

application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

.httaccess file is

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Please suggest me what to do.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: set your base url, make sure u upload .htaccess file there

Comment: The latest versions of codeigniter not recommend to leave base url blank as some of the links will not work css, java etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726776/codeigniter-url-suffix-html-automatically-for-all-url